# Is "days in the future" or "days into the future" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

When writing a sentence referencing a specific future time period, how would you correctly form the sentence?

As an example, which of the following would be correct?

1. That date is more than 5 days in the future.
2. That date is more than 5 days into the future.

Comment: There are many hits on Google for both 'days in the future' and 'days into the future'. The latter uses the metaphor of movement (going into a new 'region') while the former uses the locative metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

If you say "into the future" it is referring to movement. For example, I could say "I traveled five days into the future"

If you say "in the future" it is a bit less clear - but you can assume that they are talking about something that may happen "five days in the future I will run a marathon"

Does that help?